# Can this jQueryJjavaScript snippet be re-written more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write this code more efficiently. I've tried about 25 different permutations and it only seems to break it.

Basically, I am adding various classes to elements to trigger a css/keyframes animation when the window width is 1025px or greater.

And then there is another class being adding when it is less than 1024px which is intended to reveal the element without the element.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width >= 1025) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#about .image img.flex').each(function() {
            var position = $(this).offset().top;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("slideLeft"); }
        });
        $('#author .image img.flex').each(function() {
            var position = $(this).offset().top;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("slideRight"); }             
        });
        $('#feed .blog_01').each(function() {
            var position = $(this).offset().top;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("oneUp"); }
        });
        $('#feed .blog_02').each(function() {
            var position = $(this).offset().top;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("twoUp"); }
        });
        $('#feed .blog_03').each(function() {
            var position = $(this).offset().top;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("thrUp"); }
        });
        $('#feed .more').each(function() {
            var position = $(this).offset().top;
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (position < top+1000) { $(this).addClass("moreUp"); }
        });
    });
} 
else { 
    $('#about .image img.flex').addClass('visible'); 
    $('#author .image img.flex').addClass('visible'); 
    $('#feed .blog_01').addClass('visible');
    $('#feed .blog_02').addClass('visible');
    $('#feed .blog_03').addClass('visible');
    $('#feed .more').addClass('visible');
    }       
</script>
```

EDIT

Maybe it would be better to visualize it like this:

Perhaps it would be better to say how can I make this portion more efficient...

```
var width = $(window).width();
    if(width >= 1025) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#about .image img.flex').each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("slideLeft"); }
    });
    $('#author .image img.flex').each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("slideRight"); }             
    });
    $('#feed .blog_01').each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("oneUp"); }
    });
    $('#feed .blog_02').each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("twoUp"); }
    });
    $('#feed .blog_03').each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (position < top+600) { $(this).addClass("thrUp"); }
    });
    $('#feed .more').each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (position < top+1000) { $(this).addClass("moreUp"); }
    });'
```

Comment: Consider using media queries for this task, it should be much more efficient. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Media queries will generally be faster than explicit DOM manipulations.

Comment: Not too concerned right now on the DOM versus media query issue. I am more interested in having a more efficient function. I feel like there is a lot of repeating information in the script and was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same effect, without having to repeat the position and top variables, etc. I didn't know if there was a better way to write this globally.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By efficient, do you mean performant, like, smooth animations without jittering, or do you mean easy to read code? These are very different outcomes. Assigning a variable for every element on (and off) the page based on it's position and then running some CSS animation as a result is going to be very un-performant. If it's just code-cleanup that you want that's going to be different. Out of curiosity, how many elements on the page will be hit by these selectors?

Comment: 6-8 selectors, not too concerned with performance. It seems to run nicely now. Just looking for code that can be written using less repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@icicleking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2925767/icicleking)'s answer looks pretty great, but if you need to preserve you addClasses, you could iterate over the important values.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sefukuguca/edit?js)

```
var width = $(window).width();

// Make an array of data objects
var data = [
  { el: '#about .image img.flex', plus: 600, newClass: "slideLeft" },
  { el: '#author .image img.flex', plus: 600, newClass: "slideRight" },
  { el: '#feed .blog_01', plus: 600, newClass: "oneUp" },
  { el: '#feed .blog_02', plus: 600, newClass: "twoUp" },
  { el: '#feed .blog_03', plus: 600, newClass: "thrUp" },
  { el: '#feed .more', plus: 1000, newClass: "moreUp" }
];

if(width >= 1025) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Loop over the array of data objects
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      // For each object, target the el attribute for more looping...
      $(d.el).each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        // ...use the plus attribute in this condition...
        if (position < (top + d.plus)) {
          // ...and add the newClass attribute
          $(this).addClass(d.newClass); }
      });
    });
  });
} else { 
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    $(d.el).addClass('visible');
  });
}
```

Comment: This accomplished what I was looking for out of the box, even though I do not understand it as clearly as icicleking above. I am just a javascript novice. But this was good learning experience. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I added some comments. Leme know if you need more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat, triggering animation directly on scroll events is not an efficient way of animating. Others have written much more than I can say about this. When you say "efficient", I'm assuming here that you mean shorter, easier to read.

You could try something like this, sorry I didn't transpose your classes.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.all, .the, .selectors, .belong, .to, .us').each(function(e) {
    var position = $(this).offset().top;
    if ($(this).hasClass('.all') && position < top+1000) {
      $(this).addClass('.slideThisClass');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('.the') && position < top+600) {
      $(this).addClass('.theOtherSlideClass');
    }
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea around this one the best but I could not make it work when I added the code. After three tries I gave up and moved on. You help is greatly appreciated, and I learned that apparently you can use multiple selectors  in a function, in theory.